# Configuring django settings to work with 1.4.1. Loading template error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, osqa

Here is the error I got:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing template source loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source: "'module' object has no attribute 'load_template_source'"
```

Here is my loader template code:

```
if DEBUG:
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = [
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',      
    ]
else:
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = [
        ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader',(
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
            'forum.modules.template_loader.module_templates_loader',
            'forum.skins.load_template_source',
            )),
    ]
```

All of this code was there when I downloaded the project from the internet. I'm trying to setup [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/download/) using [these instructions](http://wiki.osqa.net/display/docs/Windows+Vista+with+SQLServer). I'm running **MS SQL Server** and have **Python 2.6** installed. Any help on how to fix this error *(found when I try to run `manage.py` runserver and hit the http link where my stuff is setup. the error pops up in the command line)*. I'm new to **Django** and **Python** so I don't really know to how to diagnose what is happening.

Comment: Compare the two TEMPLATE_LOADERS in detail. The actual problem was trying to use the old *.filesystem.load_template_source and *.app_directories.load_template_source... should be *.filesystem.Loader. However great answer @girasquid

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you look at the documentation on [template loader types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types) (scroll down to the cached template loader section), it looks like when you configure the cached loader you still need to pass it `Loader` classes - so you'd want to change your config to look like this:

```
if DEBUG:
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = [
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',      
    ]
else:
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = [
        ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader',(
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            'forum.modules.template_loader.module_templates_loader',
            'forum.skins.load_template_source',
            )),
    ]
```

I'm not sure what the loaders are for the `forum` app, but you probably also want `Loader` classes there as well (you'll need to read the documentation on that app to figure that out - not all third party template loaders work with the cached loader).

Comment: I think that fixed it because now I'm getting a different error :) which I'm pretty sure is different than this one...

Comment: Note - the function based template loaders were removed in Django 1.4: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-4.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the ‘settings.py‘ file in the folder which contains the extracted contents of the Twissandra project.
2. Search, ‘TEMPLATE_LOADERS=(‘ and within it, search, ‘django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source‘. Comment this line and add, ‘django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader‘.
3. Similarly, within ‘TEMPLATE_LOADERS=(‘, search, ‘django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source‘, and replace it with, ‘django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader‘.

> 

P.S. I solved my problem and thanks [How to fix the Django error displayed when loading Twissandra for the first time?](http://ksearch.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/how-to-fix-the-django-error-displayed-when-loading-twissandra-for-the-first-time/)