# django user Authentication error?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-authentication, django-users

i am new to django. i need to create a user log in system and i am following that tutorial [user authentication](http://rdegges.com/user-authentication-with-django)
 and i am getting a particular error

> Error importing template source loader
>   django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source: "'module'
>   object has no attribute 'load_template_source'"

i am failed to locate what went wrong.can anyone tell me in what conditions this kind of error occur?

Comment: possible duplicate : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904609/configuring-django-settings-to-work-with-1-4-1-loading-template-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is problem with your Loader Template . Try this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904609/configuring-django-settings-to-work-with-1-4-1-loading-template-error)